# PHP - Store array value in variable

Tags: php, mysql

How can I take the value from the query array result set and story it in another variable this was my attempt:

```
$countEps = Singlequery('SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_eps FROM items WHERE name = :name',
                            array('name' => $_GET['name'], ), $conn);


// Store the number of episodes
$ep = $num_eps;
```

This is what the query returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num_eps] => 15 ) )
```

Comment: `$countEps[0]['num_eps']`

Answer (score 1):

you Should do like this

```
print_r($countEps);
$ep = array();
foreach($countEps as $value){
$ep = array('num_eps' => $value['num_eps'])}
print_r($ep);
```